# How to force npm to install specific version of package by default?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to config npm not to install package using a lazy version like:

```
"coffee-script": "^1.11.1",
```

But

```
"coffee-script": "1.11.1",
```

And have this behavior become the default one? We usually don't want to use lazy versions, I prefer to manually upgrade everything to the latest from time to time rather than having a bug thrown up at my face after a new deployment due to a bug in one of my dependencies.

The only way to "do that" right now is to manually remove the `^` character every time after every `npm install`, which is a bit boring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the command that will set a user variable in your npm configuration to **always default to use the exact version** when performing an npm installation of all packages.

Enter this command in your terminal:

```
npm config set save-exact=true
```

The new preference is stored in a user-based custom npm configuration file. It is located here:

```
~/.npmrc
```

Finally, you can verify the setting was saved with the command:

```
npm config ls
```

---

Official NPM docs here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using 
`npm shrinkwrap`.
It will create npm-shrinkwrap.json which specifies the currently used versions of your dependencies and then npm install will honor that.

Then, when you want to upgrade all of your dependencies, delete the npm-shrinkwrap.json file, run npm install and re-run npm shrinkwrap. 
Or, to upgrade a single package dependency, run `npm install --save <package-name>`. This will update the npm-shrinkwrap file with that updated version info.

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Comment: Interesting, but doesn't really answer the question. It doesn't help with the `npm install`, and adds a new dependency and deployment workflow. I guess it's mostly useful for very critical systems. On my side, just ensuring the version of my own dependencies is good enough for now. :)
But definitely interesting!

Comment: This freezes your dependencies and is used specifically with npm install. It doesn't add any new dependencies; the functionality is bundled within npm. I don't know about criticality but I thin this maps well to your use case and is easy to use.